# How to place Native Ads every 3 items in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, admob

I want to place Native Ads or banners from google AdMob. It should be placed every 3 items in my RecyclerView. I found some solutions but unfortunately, it didn't work. Thanks for your help.

**Main class:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_benefits);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_benefits);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.benefits_recycler);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, benefitsList());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

**MyAdapter class:**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> {

Context c;
ArrayList<Model> models;

public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Model> models) {
    this.c = c;
    this.models = models;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_list_item, null);
    return new MyHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder myHolder, int i) {
    myHolder.mTitle.setText(models.get(i).getTitle());
    myHolder.mDescription.setText(models.get(i).getDesc());
    myHolder.mImageView.setImageResource(models.get(i).getImage());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return models.size();
}
```

**MyHolder class:**

```
public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

ImageView mImageView;
TextView mTitle, mDescription;

public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    this.mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowImage);
    this.mTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowTitle);
    this.mDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowDescription);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I did this by having my recycler view hold an interface.  Then having two implementations for the normal recycler view item and an AdHolder item. Then I just inserted an AdHolder every 3 items.

You can also follow this codelab which does something similar:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-native-advanced-feed-android/#0

Comment: the link is old,  not working